# Carrierwave save object instead filename in db or mount_uploader doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I use Carrierwave gem for uploading file, but I have a problem. Controller does not save avatar in database,  despite the fact that the object comes in params  from the view. If I remove mount_uploader from my model, Carrierwave save object in database instead filename. How can I fix it?

My user_controller.rb

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController

   before_action :set_user

    def show
    end

   def edit
   end

   def update
    if @user.update(users_params)
     redirect_to user_path(current_user.id)
    else
     puts @user.inspect
     flash.now[:alert]= 'Something wrong'
     render :edit
   end
 end
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

 def users_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
  end

  def new
  end


end
```

my user.rb model

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, 
      omniauth_providers: [:facebook]

      has_one :account, dependent: :destroy
      mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  end
```

edit.html.haml

```
.container
  %h1 Edit
  = form_for @user, html: { :multipart => true } do |f|
   = f.label :id
   = f.file_field :avatar
   = f.submit
```

avatar_uploader.rb

```
  class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  end

 def extension_whitelist
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
 end
end
```

Comment: try official git link https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave, i think  you miss carrierwave uploader

Comment: What do you mean? Including gem carrierwave(done) or carrierwave config?Or I have to add carrierwave_uploader.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object is being saved in database because you are passing complete avatar object in the params.

After you mount the uploader

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

and create & save a new user

```
u = User.new
u.avatar = params[:file] # Assign a file like this
u.save!
```

The whole avatar object gets assigned, then you can access various methods on that object to get the fields like:

```
u.avatar.url # => '/url/to/file.png'
u.avatar.current_path # => 'path/to/file.png'
u.avatar_identifier # => 'file.png'
```

If you want to save just the file name in the database, instead of passing `avatar` into user params, you can just pass `avatar.identifier`

The respective file will still be stored by the avatar uploader

Or you can yourself do that by creating uploader instance like:

```
uploader = AvatarUploader.new
uploader.store!(my_file)
```

**UPDATE:**
Since you are using Devise you have to make parameters accessible in different way. So `User.rb` should be like : 
**In Rails 5:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :remember_me, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar
end
```

In **Rails 4:** 
Instead of attr_accessible in model, params have to be whitelisted in Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password,
      :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password,
      :password_confirmation, :current_password, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar) }
  end
end
```

Comment: You mean add avatar.identifier in method users_params or change view?  I do not understand well what and where I need to change.

Comment: Firstly you should save the complete avatar object into DB as it is happening now because then you will be able to use url, identifier, thumb_url, etc methods directly on the avatar. If you still want to save only the file name/url, no need to change the views, just before creating/updating the user set the `@user[:avatar] = params[:avatar].identifier`

Comment: When I try to display avatar in view (complete avatar object in DB) 
=image_tag @user.avatar.url
it's not working and I think this is because there is not a right saving in the database. I don't want save only filename, I want to display in some view what's saved.

Comment: Have you tried `=image_tag @user.avatar_url` ? If this doesn't work post the content of the object saved in DB and the url formed using `@user.avatar_url`

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Do I need to rewrite the url for avatar? I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what do you mean exactly, I am a new in RoR.

Comment: Check the updated answer, If it still doesn't resolve your issue. I have pushed a simple user registration using devise and carrierwave, the avatar is uploaded at registration time i.e. `users/sign_up` and is shown on `users#index` route. You can find the project here https://github.com/HashBug/rails-devise-avatar